# Since when \includegraphics rejects bb?

Tags: graphics

Sorry to ask again in a few days. The fact is, that I just upgraded from TeX Live 2015 to TeX Live 2017, and a few things started misbehaving.

The result of the following test example is surprising.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Hello World\\
Mr. X\includegraphics[bb=30mm 25mm 0mm 0mm,scale=.5]{signature.png}b
\end{document}
```

The result does not include any graphics, and swaps the text too:

```
Hello World
b             Mr. X
```

I need the `bb` to place the signature with transparency on top of 
the typed name.

Why `\includegraphics` now rejects the explicit bounding box?

UPDATE

Re bb with negative values: 
It is a trick that worked very well for a long time. The graphicx manual, page 2, section 3, includes bb as option. I used this option with negative values, to move the image where it needs to be. It worked with texlive 2015. It does not work with texlive 2017.

Re \llap: 
no, it places the image to the left of the text area. Result is horrible.

Re \raisebox: 
no, I do not want to move the text around.

Re \adjustbox:
no, it places the signature on top of the name, without overlapping.

UPDATE #2

The following works with pdflatex, but fails with lualatex.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
~\\A. Dolittle, MD\\
Job title\\
~\includegraphics[bb=0 0 10 10, scale=.5]{signature.png}
\end{document}
```

With pdflatex, the two lines are printed, and the image is placed on top of them. With lualatex, no image is included at all.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.1.8)  8 JAN 2018 22:20

This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)  (format=lualatex 2018.1.8)  8 JAN 2018 22:29
```

UPDATE #3

The following works with both pdflatex and lualatex.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
~\\A. Dolittle, MD\\
Job title\\
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(-30,25){\includegraphics[scale=.5]{signature.png}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

I LOVE YOU DAVID :-)

Comment: `bb` is only for EPS files.

Comment: It used to work for PDF files as well.

Comment: No, it didn't; only `scale` was applied.

Comment: If I remove the bb, the transparent overlap does not work anymore.

Comment: @Rupert: How about using `\makebox[0pt][l]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image}} your name here`?

Comment: Tried it. Same result. No overlapping. :-(

Comment: I am reading the graphicx manual, page 2, section 3. Nowhere it says that bb is limited to EPS files.

Comment: @Rupert: No overlapping? Surely `your name here` should overlap with the image, since the image is placed in a zero-width box and the text is printed *after* the image.

Comment: I confirm, no overlapping.

Comment: The expected result is "Your name here\\additional line" first, then the signature on top of it, with the body of the signature below and above both lines.

Comment: @Rupert: [Here](https://pastebin.com/sSBfgS3E) are some options using [`adjustbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox).

Comment: I'll look at the edit, but note that TeX-sx isn't the best place to report bugs: they should go to the relevant bug database. Here: https://github.com/latex3/graphics-def/issues. (In particular, engine variations of this type may rate to the image file concerned: the LaTeX driver code is as close to identical as possible between pdfTeX and LuaTeX.)

Comment: Any behaviour of bb with implicit negative size was only the result of a lack of error checking to reject that input (as it never occurred to me that that would be necessary) If it produced an offset that you expected then that was only by accidental, untested code. Note that bb is documented as providing the coordinates of the bottom left and top right coordinates, this does imply that the first two coordinates are smaller values than the second two. Personally I would use picture mode and `\put(???,??)` to over-print the text and graphic in whatever positions are needed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Looks like your comment is the answer. Please post it as one, the Rupert can accept it to conclude the question.

Answer (score 9):

If driver `pdftex.def` is used (`pdflatex`), then option `bb` is not supported, because pdfTeX is able to extract the size of the image formats it supports (e.g., PDF, PNG, JPEG, ...). As `bb` specifies the bounding box of the image and pdfTeX already knows the bounding box (/MediaBox, ...), `bb` serves no purpose and as error recovery option `viewport` is used instead. This behavior was implemented many, many years before; from the revision history (at the top of `pdftex.def`):

```
% 2000/09/14 v0.03e
%  * Options `bbllx', `bblly', `bburx', `bbury' disabled,
%    option `bb' redirected with a warning to `viewport' (HO).
```

From the question:

```
\includegraphics[bb=30mm 25mm 0mm 0mm,scale=.5]{signature.png}
```

The values for `bb` or `viewport` are quite wrong, from the [documentation of LaTeX's graphics bundle](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf):

> - `bb`     The argument should be four dimensions, separated by spaces. These denote   the `Bounding Box' of the printed region
>     within the file.
> - `bbllx`,`bblly`,`bburx`,`bbury`    Set the bounding box. Mainly for compatibility  with older packages. Specifying
>     `bbllx=a,bblly=b,bburx=c,bbury=d` is  equivalent to specifying `bb = a b c d`.
> - `viewport`    The `viewport` key takes four arguments, just like `bb`. However  in this case the values are taken relative to the
>     origin specified by the  bounding box in the file. So to `view' the 1
>     in square in the bottom left  hand corner of the area specified by the
>     bounding box, use the argument  `viewport=0 0 72 72`.

`bb=30mm 25mm 0mm 0mm` or `viewport=30mm 25mm 0mm 0mm` means that the width (-30mm) and height (-25mm) are negative. The four parameters are
left (llx), bottom (lly), right (urx), and top (ury) with the x axis from left to right and the y axis from bottom to top.

A negative width or height is an user error and confuses package `graphics/graphicx`). For example, LaTeX moves 30mm to the left, thus that `b` after the image is drawn left of `Mr. X` that is written before the image in the source.

Fix the values, e.g. `viewport=0mm 0mm 30mm 25mm`, to get back to the documented behavior.

There are lots of ways to place an image. For example, it can be put to the left and overwriting the left text by putting it in `\llap`:

```
Mr. X\llap{\includegraphics[scale=.5]{signature.png}}
```

`\raisebox` with its options (also check the optional options) can be used to place the image vertically. Another way is offered by environment `picture`.

Comment: Re \\llap: it places the image to the left of the text area. Result is horrible.

Comment: Re \raisebox: no, I do not want to move the text around.

Comment: Re bb with negative values: It is a trick that worked very well for a long time.  The graphicx manual, page 2, section 3, includes bb as option. I used this option with negative values, to move the image where it needs to be. It worked with texlive 2015. It does not work with texlive 2017.

Comment: @Rupert `\llap` puts the contents to the left (it also does not start a new paragraph unlike `\mbox`). If you put it at the left border of the text area, it places the image to the left of the text area. You haven't given any example, how you have used it. Also the question left out important details, how large the image is and where you want to place the image exactly.

Comment: @Rupert You can only fix the vertical position with `\raisebox` with the *correct* arguments. But you cannot move the image "around".

Comment: @Rupert Using invalid arguments that might work in some version with some driver has the big disadvantage that it can stop working with any other context (version, driver, ...), even without any notice. IMHO, the packages `graphics` and `graphicx` can be improved by checking for option settings that lead to a negative image width or height and throw a decent error message.

Answer (score 4):

I tried your example with a default PNG image. With TeX Live from 2012 to 2016 I get the warning

```
Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def)                using `viewport' instead on input line 5.
```

So, no, it has never worked. It *sort of* did, but the support was not really precise.

Comment: I used it for at least 15 years, same code, and it worked *very well* on PDF.

Comment: @Rupert No. You got a warning, at least in the last five years.

Comment: We both have evidence. I cannot recall the warning, but I recall very well that the signature overlapped the typed name, and it was spectacular. Now, the trick is broken.

Comment: And I have 15 years of signed documents to prove it.

Comment: @Rupert Well, somebody forgot to write it when support for different graphic files was added.

Comment: If I look into the log, I see this: << 
File: signature.png Graphic file (type png)
<use signature.png>
Package luatex.def Info: signature.png  used on input line 50.
(luatex.def)             Requested size: -42.67902pt x -35.56584pt.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 51. >> There are neither warnings nor errors.

Comment: @Rupert That `viewport` is used with a warning instead of `bb` was introduced in the year 2000 in driver `pdftex.def`.  If you haven't noticed this in the last 15 years, this means either you are not using `pdflatex`, or you use software that is older than 17 years. BTW, `luatex.def` is much younger, but it inherits from `pdftex.def`.

Comment: I guess I'll need to re-introduce the recovery code here, even though I _really_ don't like the idea of messing with the bounding box of images _at all_ ...

Comment: @Rupert Relax and be happy that a collection of the best LaTeX experts of this community are willing to help you free of charge  :). Your problem seems to be solved within less than two hours, isn't that great

Answer (score 3):

As-of release 2018-01-01, the `pdftex` and `luatex` drivers revert to treating `bb` as equivalent to `viewport` (see https://github.com/latex3/graphics-def/commit/9e6d682fe28c3811410e0faae70c75e586fc8b05). In contrast to the earlier behaviour (described in [Heiko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407951)), this mapping is treated as 'information' not a warning.

Comment: no. I get an error, not a warning (pdftex TL2019)

Answer (score 2):

Any behaviour of `bb` with implicit negative size was only the result of a lack of error checking to reject that input (as it never occurred to me that that would be necessary) If it produced an offset that you expected then that was only by accidental, untested code. Note that `bb` is documented as providing the coordinates of the bottom left and top right coordinates, this does imply that the first two coordinates are smaller values than the second two. Personally I would use picture mode and `\put(???,??)` to over-print the text and graphic in whatever positions are needed